# Master commit then merge with another branch

Tags: git, merge

I've never tried this before. Suppose that you have two branches "master" and "aBranch", you create aBranch then commit master branch which is ahead of aBranch. Always I merge with branch that are ahead of master but not in reverse.
What will happen if you merge master (which is ahead) with aBranch when no conflicting files are involved?

Comment: Git doesn't care about branch names.  There is nothing special about `master` in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the relationship between `master` and `aBranch`. If your history looks something like this:

```
* (master)
|
*
|
* (aBranch)
```

then nothing happens, since `master` can already reach every commit reachable from `aBranch`.

If, instead, you have something like

```
* (master)
|
*  * (aBranch)
|  |
*  *
| /
*
```

then you get just what you would if you tried to merge the other way. The only difference is the order in which the merge commit stores its two parents, and which branch head is advanced.

```
* (master)
| \
*  |
|  |
*  * (aBranch)
|  |
*  *
| /
*
```